# How to get coordinates where two curves joint?

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

I have a question about ggplot2 geom_density plot, my data like:

```
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c(1,2,3), 33), Value = runif(99, min = 0,max = 50))
```

How to get the coordinate of the **red star** in the example graph:

[image: Example]

Comment: What do you mean 'this point'? How would you define that point? I can see that point being as some point along the density curve where the difference between the two groups is minimized. However, this is true for many points on the graph (the right tail where both densities are close to zero, for example). What else is important about that point? Also, how exact do you need the coordinates of that point? Is a discretised approximation good enough?

Comment: I want to get this point as a cutoff to separate this curve into two groups, from the example plot, it seems like around 5(x axis), but I want to know the exact value.